# SQL Server: How do I add a constraint to an existing table but only if the constraint does not already exist?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to add a constraint to an existing SQL server table but only if it does not already exist.

I am creating the constraint using the following SQL.

```
ALTER TABLE [Foo] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Foo_Bar] FOREIGN KEY ([BarId]) REFERENCES [Bar] ([BarId]) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
```

I'm hoping I can add some SQL to the begining of the SQL to test for the existence of the constraint but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Personally I would drop the existing constraint, and recreate it - in case the one that is already there is in some way different

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'[dbo].[MyFKName]') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsForeignKey') = 1)
    ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTableName DROP CONSTRAINT MyFKName
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTableName ADD CONSTRAINT [MyFKName] ...
```

The current, more modern, code I am using is:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[MyFKName]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[MyTableName]'))
    ALTER TABLE dbo.[MyTableName] DROP CONSTRAINT [MyFKName]
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.[MyTableName] ADD CONSTRAINT [MyFKName] FOREIGN KEY ...
```

not sure if there is any advantage of checking sys.objects ... or sys.foreign_keys ... but at some point I decided on sys.foreign_keys

Starting with SQL2016 new "IF EXISTS" syntax was added which is a lot more readable:

```
-- For SQL2016 onwards:
ALTER TABLE dbo.[MyTableName] DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS [MyFKName]
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.[MyTableName] ADD CONSTRAINT [MyFKName] FOREIGN KEY ...
```

Comment: dbo.sysobjects will be removed in a future version.  For SQL 2005 and up use sys.objects instead.

Answer (score 12):

I'd recommend using the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS view. It's portable across different database engines:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME='Foo' 
AND CONSTRAINT_NAME='FK_Foo_Bar' 
AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE='FOREIGN KEY'
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if the constraint already exists before adding it -

```
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'FK_Foo_Bar')
    BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTableName ADD CONSTRAINT [MyFKName] ...
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

Drop the default constraint and create your own. ALTER table TABLE_NAME drop constraint  CONSTRAINT NAME
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TABLE_NAME] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_TABLE_NAME_COLUMN_NAME]  FOR [COLUMN_NAME]

Answer (score 0):

Very simple:

IF OBJECT_ID('Schema.keyname') IS NULL

ALTER TABLE Schema.tablename ADD CONSTRAINT keyname...

Comment: doesn't work for default constraints either

Answer (score -1):

```
Alter table tableName add constraint constraintname default 0  for columnname
```

You can provide constraintname as you want without single quote

Comment: that was not the question